# How to select Multiple Date and time in Jquery calendar?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

How To select multiple date with time in calender. Here selectng multiple dates from using "multidatespicker" js file,Is It possible to select multi-times with multiple dates? if yes ,can any one help me.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-multidatespicker@1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="App_Themes/NM_Themes/CSS/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<td class='input-group date'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" style="width: 218px; height: 25px" id='txtmulDos' />
</td>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#txtPtDOB').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just FYI - the `.datetimepicker()` is not a jQuery UI widget.

Comment: jquery and bootstrap3

Comment: any suggestion plz

Comment: http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/